# How to pass an List<Integer> Object and String in Rest Services in Android

Tags: java, android, rest

Hi  I am woring for a Quiz App, so I need to call post rest services(json),below one is my sample code which is not working

I need to pass 3 thing as parameter 1-userid, 2-List questionids and 3- List answerIds. My Question is how to  pass List Object not String or Json String here-

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", "121213"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("questionsids", listobj);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("answerIds", listObj));

    HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Is There any other way to call the post rest service.How to resolve above one?

Thanks
Ranjan.

Answer (score 0):

use for loop and add with same key.

Like this:

> ```
> List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
> for (ModelAssignee assignee : assignmentChips.getAssignees())
> {
>   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AssignedToIds", String.valueOf(assignee.Id)));
> }
> ```

Comment: @nasim thanks for your answer, I need to try your solution  but is there any other way to pass list object in rest post services,please let me know.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I need to try your solution but is there any other way to pass list object in rest post services,please let me know.